# Ordinary Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was doing this question with the equation as shown in [Screenshot]
and I was wondering how would I be able to solve this, I am getting a plus instead of a minus sign in part c this question [parts c and d](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDG3q.png)!

Would greatly appreciate any hints or help for part c and d, as I have been working on this for days already.

Thank you in advance kind people!

Comment: Try removing the non linear terms by composition of the two equations.

Comment: Do you mean add them up?

Comment: If yes, I tried that but I am getting plus signs instead of minus signs as the question required

Comment: I mean scaling, then subtracting.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really can't see what you mean by that? Can you kindly try and illustrate that?

Comment: What do I scale by?

Comment: Multiply the first equation by $B_m$ and the second by $B_f$.

Comment: I see, after which, I would get this, $B_m$ (df/df) - $B_f$ (dm/dt)  = $D_f$ ($B_f$ m - $B_m$ f). How would I integrate this.

Comment: Try to differentiate $g=B_mf-B_fm$ with respect to $t$ and see if you can find a closed form for $g$.

Comment: My coefficients seems that it needs to be the reciprocals instead. Is there something wrong with my step?

Comment: You have $-Dt$ at the RHS. Then apply initial condition and, after that, if you really need the same expression as in point C, you just need to divide both sides by $B_mB_f$.

Comment: Oh I viewed the symbols wrongly, my bad, I mistook $B_f$ as $B_m$! Thanks a million, N74 :)